# Two prove two lines in a triangle are parallel

Tags: euclidean-geometry

$D$, $E$, $F$ are the midpoints of sides $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ respectively of a triangle $ABC$ right angled at $C$. If $EF$ and $DF$ (extended if necessary), meet the perpendicular from $C$ on $AB$ in points $G$ and $H$ respectively, show that $AG$ is parallel to $BH$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: It would be a good thing to tell what you tried and maybe add a picture.

Comment: Is this a good picture for your question?


http://i.stack.imgur.com/aPRFk.png

Comment: @zoli I have made some alternations to your picture according to the question statement.

Comment: After making a more accurate drawing according to your description, I found that AG will NOT be parallel to BH. Please check your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing the typo, the correct figure is:-

[image]

By midpoint theorem, 1) $GE // BC$; 2) $GE$ and $HD$ are the perpendicular bisectors of $AC$ and $BC$ respectively.

$\epsilon + \theta = 2 \theta = 2 \mu = \mu + \rho = \phi$

Result follows.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution yet. It is just a picture to clarify a few things.

[image]

Comment: yes it is the actual picture but could not go beyond this

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula What is the source? Could there be typos?

Comment: there is a typo i have corrected it and gave the answer

Answer (score 0):

construction: extend CE to meet BH in J and extend AG to meet  CE in I

Now consider the triangle ACE.We have CK is perpendicular to AE and EF is perpendicular to AC.Therefore G is the orthocentre of triangle ACE.Therefore, AI is another altitude.So we have angle AIE is a right angle.

Now consider the triangle BHC.By a similar argument we can prove that E is orthocentre of triangle BHC. Therefore, angle CJH is a right angle.

Thus,it is established that angle AIE=angle HJE.Therefore, AG is parallel to BH.